# Aligning table row at middle

Tags: context

I have this trigonometric table:

[image]

Their columns are correctly aligned in the middle, but the rows aren't.

So, how can I get a row middle aligned text too?

Working example is followed:

```
\starttext
\midaligned{
    \setupTABLE[c][each][align=middle, width=1.3cm]
    \bTABLE
        \bTR \bTD $\theta$ \eTD \bTD $0°$ \eTD \bTD $30°$ \eTD \bTD $45°$ \eTD \bTD $60°$ \eTD \bTD $90°$ \eTD \eTR
        \bTR \bTD $sin(\theta)$ \eTD \bTD $0$ \eTD \bTD $\frac{1}{2}$ \eTD \bTD $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ \eTD \bTD $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ \eTD \bTD $1$ \eTD \eTR
        \bTR \bTD $cos(\theta)$ \eTD \bTD $1$ \eTD \bTD $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ \eTD \bTD $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ \eTD \bTD $\frac{1}{2}$ \eTD \bTD $0$ \eTD \eTR
        \bTR \bTD $tan(\theta)$ \eTD \bTD $0$ \eTD \bTD $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ \eTD \bTD $1$ \eTD \bTD $\sqrt{3}$ \eTD \bTD $\infty$ \eTD \eTR
    \eTABLE
}
\stoptext
```

Comment: Off-topic: Whatever else you choose to do, please write `\sin`, `\cos`, and `\tan`, not `sin`, `cos`, and `tan`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control the vertical alignment of the cell content with the `low`, `lohi` and `high` keywords for the `align` key.

```
\starttext

\startlinealignment[middle]
  \bTABLE[width=2cm,height=2cm,align={middle,lohi}]
    \bTR
      \bTD \eTD
      \bTD left \eTD
      \bTD middle \eTD
      \bTD right \eTD
    \eTR
    \bTR
      \bTD low \eTD
      \bTD[align={flushleft,low}] TEXT \eTD
      \bTD[align={middle,low}] TEXT \eTD
      \bTD[align={flushright,low}] TEXT \eTD
    \eTR
    \bTR
      \bTD middle \eTD
      \bTD[align={flushleft,lohi}] TEXT \eTD
      \bTD[align={middle,lohi}] TEXT \eTD
      \bTD[align={flushright,lohi}] TEXT \eTD
    \eTR
    \bTR
      \bTD high \eTD
      \bTD[align={flushleft,high}] TEXT \eTD
      \bTD[align={middle,high}] TEXT \eTD
      \bTD[align={flushright,high}] TEXT \eTD
    \eTR
  \eTABLE
\stoplinealignment

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked beautiful. The secret was `align={middle,lohi}`